# Agregar un valor especifico a un arreglo bidimensional c++

Tags: c++

Tengo mi arreglo [3][7], el 3 representa a los monos, y el 7 representa la cantidad de alimento por dia, el chiste es que quiero meter las libras en el segundo arreglo que es hasta[7] pero no se como, ya intente, pero me da error, no se como se hace, alguien me podría ilustrar? gracias amigos de la comunidad

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int monos[3][7];
    string dias[] = {"lunes", "martes", "miercoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sabado", "domingo"};
    int libras = 0;
    int total[3];
    int mayor = 0;
    int aux=0;

    cout << "Información sobre los monos" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Mono numero: " << i + 1 << endl;
        monos[i][0] = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            cout << "Digite la comida del dia " << dias[j] << endl;
            cin >> libras;
            
            while (libras < 0) {
                cout << "No puede introducir una cantidad negativa, intente nuevamente:";
                cin >> libras;
            }
            libras=monos[j];
            aux+=libras;
            



        }
    }
```

Comment: "*pero no se como, ya intente, pero me da error*" ¿Qué error?

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de indentar bien las lineas de código y que las aperturas y cierre de ciclos coincidan. Por otro lado, en la parte del while me parece más práctico hacerlo con una condición if.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int monos[3][7];
    string dias[] = {"lunes", "martes", "miercoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sabado", "domingo"};
    int libras = 0;
    int total[3];
    int mayor = 0;


    cout << "Información sobre los monos" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Mono numero: " << i + 1 << endl;
        monos[i][0] = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            cout << "Digite la comida del dia " << dias[j] << endl;
            cin >> libras;




            while (libras < 0) {
                cout << "No puede introducir una cantidad negativa, intente nuevamente:";
                cin >> libras;
            }





        }


    }

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Me olvide de comentarte, no se si el enunciado del ejercicio que estas realizando especifica los tipos de datos, pero seria prudente poner la variable de libras de tipo float y no int.